# Andengine one single sprite for whole game

Tags: android, andengine, sprite, game-engine

I'm developing a game with andengine.And I wanna use only one image for whole game.
For example now I'm using 10 image spreadly.(e.g player,  buttons, background, etc.).But when I do like that, the game is starting too slow.And I wanna combine them as one image like this:
http://atariage.com/forums/uploads/monthly_11_2011/post-26314-0-86776700-1321332409.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for TexturePacker. You can find an interesting tutorial in the link below.-

http://www.matim-dev.com/texture-packer.html

Comment: and mine is gles1 so it didn't work.How can I add it to my project?